# Defining a constant array in Laravel or PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to define a constant of array. How can I do that?

```
define("CREDIT_REPORT_FAIL", "FAIL");
```

Comment: create custom [config](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#accessing-configuration-values) file for your values.

Comment: You mean array of constants?

Comment: PHP7 lets you do `define("CONSTANT_NAME", ["CREDIT_REPORT_FAIL", "FAIL"]);` ut you can't do that in earlier versions of PHP

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, do you just want something like `const CREDIT_REPORT = ['FAIL', 'SUCCESS'];`? That is possible if you are on php 5.6+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try This Code

Define Code

```
define('TEST', serialize(array(1, 5, 10, 15)));
```

Use

```
$data = unserialize(TEST);
```

Comment: this code is use in laravel and core php both?

Comment: yes it's use in both,  serialize convert into string and than unserialize is convert array..

Comment: Did you know that PHP 7 already support constant contained array using `define`? http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php

Comment: yes i know but this method is working on all version ..

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel you can define an array in a [config file](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration):

```
'some_array' => [
    'var' => 'value',
    'another_var' => 'value'
],
```

And then you [`config()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-config) global helper to get the array:

```
config('config_file.some_array')
```

Comment: `Config::get('config_file.some_array');` what about this

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud it does absolutely the same job, but `config()` is easier to use and [easier to read](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#use-shorter-and-more-readable-syntax-where-possible).